# Got no answers, got too low reputation for a bounty, just give up?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I hope this is the right place for the following issue: my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72425408/interrupt-not-prevent-from-starting-screensaver-with-python) got only one non-helpful comment. Now two months later, I have still not been able to come up with a solution on my own.

As I have little experience and thereby few reputation points I can not offer a bounty.

What do I do in a situation like this?

1. Post a duplicate (and risk being punished for that, right?)?
2. Do I simply add a comment to the question to make the question appear active?
3. Do I give up trying to get help on SO for this question?

Comment: It's possible that adding the [tag:winapi] tag would help your question reach people with the proper background to answer it. But your question may have already been answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1626566/allow-bluetooth-devices-to-wake-pc).

Comment: If you can access the [SO] chat (you can) and your question is old enough (it is) you can also ask for help in the Python chat room. See the [room rules](https://sopython.com/chatroom) first, though. FWIW, I think this is less of a Python and more of a Windows issue, so your milage may vary when approaching this as the former and not the latter.

Comment: And, for the record, you're probably not going to get an answer.  Accessing the alternative desktop screensavers run in is non-trivial, depends on the version of windows, and just generally a bad idea.  I'm not even sure it's possible without elevation.

Comment: @Anon Coward: could you pls comment briefly on why it is 'generally a bad idea' and what is 'elevation'? Thank you.

Comment: Without knowing it, you're asking how to cross the security boundary into the session the screensaver runs in.  Crossing security boundaries can lead to security issues .. the barriers are sometimes there for a reason, after all.  Elevation here means UAC elevation, allowing your script to run with administrator privileges.

Comment: @Gimby the OP obviously confuses comments and answers. There no answer on this question, deleted or not.

Comment: The initial comment was not helpful in solving the question. It just says that someone doesn't understand why someone else would want to do that programmatically.

Comment: @MartinSmith which is actually helpful in solving the question, just not the question that the OP asked but the underlying problem: why do you need to do this.

Comment: If they didn't need to do it why would they be motivated to ask the question and still be looking for an answer 2 months later?

Comment: @MartinSmith have you not seen someone so entrenched on their apparent solution that doesn't try to look for an alternative? I've seen people on this very site for years trying to get SE to implement another sorting for answers, and when they finally get it, it doesn't solve the underlying problem: answers are still obsolete and in need of an update.

Comment: The answer "get out of screensaver mode manually" is presumably what they have been doing in the interim and finding inadequate

Comment: @MartinSmith exactly, but that doesn't explain why they need to get out of screensaver mode at all. Why do they need to get out of screensaver mode when data arrives from the BT device?

Comment: Looks like it now has a bounty, thanks to [*not a robot*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19123103/not-a-robot) (whose account happens to be 2 months old)... although I'm curious if during those 2 months you thought to [check Google](https://google.com/search?q=python+cancel+screen+saver) or [other questions on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+cancel+OR+quit+screen+saver+site%3Astackoverflow.com) to find a suitable solution (like possibly, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20456756/8112776)?)

Comment: I remember there was somebody on the internet who claimed questions are not to be asked on stackoverflow because all the answers are here already. I say ignore the haters and risk the punishment, eventually you get an answer.

Comment: @ashleedawg - so the question is - is it a duplicate account ?

Comment: @RohitGupta, I'd question why someone would open a 2nd account, then work to get enough points to put a bounty on a question from their 1st account when they could have just done the work on the 1st account. Especially when the "2nd" account is 14 days older than the question being asked about. And both accounts have been active pretty much the whole time, and not participated on similar topics except for Python.

Comment: @ashleedawg ohh dear if you would have read my post in its entirety your curiosity would have been stilled and you would not have had to post your comment. The solution you suggest (like possibly, this one?) is EXACTLY the one I tried which did not work.

Comment: @mortpiedra, unfortunately, not reading a question and making assumptions is kind of common. I asked a question nearly 2 years ago that the only person commenting on it suggested 3 articles I had in the question. When I made them aware of this, their comments and my question was deleted.

Comment: @Braiam and others - overapplication of the XY principle is extremely unhelpful.  The original question is clear and precise: "how can I interrupt the screen saver".  If the answer is "you can't", explain why; if the answer is "I don't know how to do that", remain silent and let others help.  The OP's design decisions about *why* he/she wants to interrupt are out of scope.

Comment: @AnonCoward the security/escalation considerations would make a good basis for an answer to the question (of the variety "you won't be able to do this because...").  I'm not sure why nobody has mentioned that in the original SO forum, though.

Comment: @KenWilliams Care to explain/define exactly what "overapplication of the XY principle" means (*to you*)? It's extremely common to be able to quickly understand the issue with solution Y an OP is asking about, and asking why they are trying to do that or getting to the root issue X is a great way of getting to provide an answer "...you can't. Here's why... This is what you can do instead...".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel All right then, I tried my best to [explain it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72425408/interrupt-not-prevent-from-starting-screensaver-with-python/73286378#73286378).  I mostly avoid over long explanations like this, since I'm told I come off condescending, but I honestly tried to be as simplistic and straightforward as possible.  It's a surprisingly complex question.

Comment: Well, you are lucky! Because when I asked here, there are 2/7 chance they vote down or vote for close the question even I registered for over 9 years. So, now, I just read & comment.

Comment: @mortpiedra, why not edit your question? I check the questions by Activity (not by Newer) and I imagine I'm not unique (About your question, sorry, I don't know about pynton)

Comment: @Yarco - yeah meta can certainly be capricious and unpredictable. On another day this question could have received an entirely different reception.

Comment: or raise awarness by posting on meta.stackoverflow, seemed to have work.

Comment: @computercarguy well there are some survival bias here. People make mistakes sometimes (mistakenly assume OP did not try solution X while they did, or mistakenly assume X is a solution while it's not), but over 10000000 questions or so it builds up, and there ends up being some frustrating OP complaining.

Comment: @Braiam that is not really a good example. In your case, the X is "reduce outdated answers", the Y is "alternative sorting". In this case, "how to get screensaver running, but stop it when Bluetooth data arrives" is something that OP reasonably want *by itself*. (... that having said, if you are really strict the actual X here is "how to get something-similar-to-a-screensaver on the screen but stop it when Bluetooth data arrives", so *that* can also be implemented by, I guess, disabling the screensaver entirely and reimplement the functionality in Python. But I don't think that differs much)

Comment: @user202729 no, the X is "making sure that information on the site doesn't get stale and when it does we can deal with it". Why I want to reduce outdated answers, I do not care that the answer is obsolete, I care that there's an answer that is up-to-date and that it is the first one.

Comment: @Braiam Okay then. My point stands though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I posted a possible answer to your question, though as I pointed out in the answer, it's not a general answer.  It might work for your use case, and if it does, that's great.  Notably, it doesn't work for me, I had to test it out in a VM, since my machine is sufficiently locked down there is no real way to disable the screen saver from code and return to the active session .. by design.

> What do I do in a situation like this?

Answering this meta question is hard.  Really, at the heart of things, we have an XY problem.  I try to answer for the general case on Stack Overflow.  For the general case for your question the answer is "don't do that.  Use `SetThreadExecutionState` to prevent the screen saver from running, show a full-screen top-most window to act as a screen saver and make it flash or otherwise alert the user when your condition is meet"

That's however super not satisfying when you expect the answer to be a simple "call foo() to move the mouse cursor and disable the screen saver".  You just need to know what "foo()" is!  And to make matters worse, there *is* a "foo()", I showed you one possibility of it after all.  The other answer around terminating a process works too, albeit in a way that's a bit like using a bomb to open a jar of pickles.

I know I personally struggle to know when to answer these sort of questions as is, and not worry about the inherent XY problem, and when to go into little dissertations about the XY problem and solve the underlying problem.  It's a balancing act, and sometimes things are missed, since I tend to just skip over things that make me struggle internally since previous encounters with others has taught me people just want answers, not more problems.

I'm open to suggestions here.

Answer (score 59):

I'll answer generally rather than regarding your specific post.

> 1. post a duplicate?

No, definitely not.

> 2. Do I simply add a comment to the question to make the question appear active?

Mmm... that's a bit spammy... I wouldn't recommend it, and I doubt it would be useful.

> 3. Do I give up trying to get help on SO for this question?

Perhaps. It's not inconceivable that your question may just fall between the cracks. But - don't give up until you've tried a few other things:

4. Invest some time in **improving your question**:

   - Find and apply more appropriate tags
   - Add a concrete example if applicable
   - Improve phrasing and grammar.
   - Shorten sentences.
   - Add relevant context, e.g. via links.
   - Explain what you've tried.
5. Enter a **chat** room relevant to your question (e.g. the language-specific rooms), ask if someone can help you with your question about XYZ; add a link and perhaps repeat the gist of the question briefly.

Comment: You missed the approach which was successful for the OP: post about the situation here.

Comment: @skomisa: I intentionally avoided recommending that. Don't think we want that to become a popular custom.

Comment: @skomisa He had a good attitude and wasn't complaining. That's why it worked.  And the question wasn't bad. It could have easily backfired in any number of ways.

Comment: @TheMaster: That might be true for OP, but I said I was offering a general answer.

Comment: To be fair "general answers" are already at the "general post" i.e. [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer). Anyway... thinking about it *what exactly* is bad about bumping question (without any progress)? (I mean it gives you unfair advantage against those who do not bump, but if everyone does that they you don't really get anything)

Comment: Will edits/improvents on a question make at visible in the overview again? Otherwise I see how 4. would help..

Comment: @NotX: Well, it will still be a question with no answer, I think those come up in review queues, don't they? Also, remember that at some point other people will find this question, even if OP has abandoned it, and it's good to have good questions :-)

Comment: @einpoklum: Well, tbh. my impression is: if a question wasn't answered by first day, it's lost. The only chance it has then is that somebody else has this very question and stumbles upon the exisitng one, comes up with an own solution later on and provides it.

Comment: @NotX: 1. tag subscriptions. 2. [Review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review) - look at Triage and First Questions specifically.

Answer (score 36):

I started a bounty on your question because your use case sounded interesting. It kind of reminded me of the time (a long time ago) I tried to mess with my screensaver to read Yahoo! Messenger messages.

<sub><sub>Although it’s none of my business, I’m curious to know what kind of data you receive.</sub></sub>

Comment: And for the record, I only know this because ages ago I dug into the madness of how Screen Savers work since I wanted a feed reader to be able to pop up messages over the screen saver.  That code is long gone, but apparently the pain isn't.

Comment: While this is certainly kind, and is perhaps a one-off solution to the OP's problem, this doesn't actually solve the meta-problem of "how can SO better highlight the real gaps in information / burning questions if these questions are posted by people with relatively little SO experience?"  The meta answer within your question would essentially be to rely on the innate curiosity of people with reputation but not direct experience to elevate your question to greater attention, which isn't really satistying / realistic in most cases

Comment: interesting how this worked out.  the bounty got some attention and a decent answer. wonder if people might spend a bit more time to answer these answerless questions after a certain period of time if there was reputation reward?

Comment: @dangel what, you don't think the Necromancer badge is enough?

Comment: @dangel You're suggesting something like a low-level automatic bounty for answerless questions of some age? It's a neat thought, though I imagine it'd be a hard sell for the SO devs.

Answer (score 16):

If you've really tried for two months, you have experience. Use that experience to help others. There's always someone with lesser experience than you. Focus on other user's problems and submit well written answers. If that's not possible, improve other user's posts by submitting edits. You'll gain reputation and use that reputation to offer a bounty.

Answer (score 3):

When I google the error message from your question, I find [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=pywintypes.error:+(0,+%27SetCursorPos%27,+%27No+error+message+is+available%27)+site:stackoverflow.com).  Is the answer to your question in there?  I don't know.  But it seems like there are other things that you can try:

1. Use [`ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(x, y)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27344751/6660678) instead of win32api.
2. [Run as admin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42322489/6660678).
3. [Surround the command with a `try`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17512802/6660678) to get more debugging information.

What happens when you try those?  Add that information to your original question (as an edit, not a comment).  Unless it works.  If it works, post that as a self-answer.

Similarly, you might check out [these results](https://www.google.com/search?q=stop+screen+saver+windows+10+programmatically+site:stackoverflow.com).  Because apparently it's not moving the cursor that you want but just to interrupt the screen saver.  Does [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66212525/6660678)?  It seems to suggest that moving the cursor won't work and proposes VB/C# that would.  Again, if you get more negative information, edit your question.  If you figure it out, post an answer.

Or look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3527690/6660678).  It's aimed at [Delphi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi), but there might be a Python version of `GetDesktopWindow()` that would take the same WM_SYSCOMMAND/SC_SCREENSAVE message.  Linking to a few posts like this might help other people work out something for your problem.

Posting a duplicate is unlikely to change anything.  Adding new information, particularly the debugging information from catching the exception, might allow someone to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

> What do I do in a situation like this?

You earn reputation points by answering questions, and then you use those points to start a bounty on your question.

Regardless, you can't expect your question to be answered. You are not owed anything; this is a network where people help each other for free.